# Crawl urls from sitemap.xml using Apify Puppeteer and requestQueue

Tags: puppeteer, apify

Apify can crawl links from sitemap.xml

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const requestList = new Apify.RequestList({
        sources: [{ requestsFromUrl: 'https://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/cnn/news.xml' }],
    });
    await requestList.initialize();

    const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
        requestList,
        handlePageFunction: async ({ page, request }) => {
            console.log(`Processing ${request.url}...`);
            await Apify.pushData({
                url: request.url,
                title: await page.title(),
                html: await page.content(),
            });
        },
    });

    await crawler.run();
    console.log('Done.');
});
```

https://sdk.apify.com/docs/examples/puppeteersitemap#docsNav

However, I am not sure how to crawl links from sitemap.xml if I am using requestQueue. For ex:

```
const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();
await requestQueue.addRequest({url: "https://google.com});

 //this is not working. Apify is simply crawling sitemap.xml 
 //and not adding urls from sitemap.xml to requestQueue
 await requestQueue.addRequest({url:`https://google.com/sitemap.xml`});

 const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
    requestQueue,

    // This function is called for every page the crawler visits
    handlePageFunction: async (context) => {


        const {request, page} = context;

        const title = await page.title();
        let page_url = request.url;
        console.log(`Title of ${page_url}: ${title}`);

        await Apify.utils.enqueueLinks({
            page, selector: 'a', pseudoUrls, requestQueue});
    },


});

await crawler.run();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The great thing about Apify is that you can use both `RequestList` and `RequestQueue` together. In that case, items are taken from the list to the queue as you scrape (not overloading the queue). By using both, you get the best from both worlds.

```
Apify.main(async () => {
    const requestList = new Apify.RequestList({
        sources: [{ requestsFromUrl: 'https://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/cnn/news.xml' }],
    });
    await requestList.initialize();

    const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();

    const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
        requestList,
        requestQueue,
        handlePageFunction: async ({ page, request }) => {
            console.log(`Processing ${request.url}...`);

            // This is just an example, define your logic
            await Apify.utils.enqueueLinks({
                page, selector: 'a', pseudoUrls: null, requestQueue,
            });
            await Apify.pushData({
                url: request.url,
                title: await page.title(),
                html: await page.content(),
            });
        },
    });

    await crawler.run();
    console.log('Done.');
});
```

If you want to use just the queue, you will need to parse the XML yourself. Of course, this is not a big issue. You can parse it easily with [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) either before the crawler or by using `Apify.CheerioCrawler`

Anyway, we recommend using `RequestList` for bulk urls because it is basically instantly created in-memory but the queue is actually a database (or JSON files locally).

Comment: thanks. I was trying to get all urls from sitemap.xml. I did not realize that `"requestList.initialize()"` method can download sitemap.xml and parse urls from sitemap.xml  `await requestList.initialize();`

Comment: Yeah, the magic is in the `requestsFromUrl`. It uses a regex to scan the URL (it can be HTML, CSV, XML, TXT, JSON etc.) for URLs and creates a request list from that.